# Как в C++ найти наибольший делитель числа?

Tags: c++

Пользователь вводит число N, нужно найти наибольший делитель числа N, не равный N.

Comment: Найдите наименьший - тогда наибольший будет это число, деленное на наименьший делитель...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    cin >> n;
    int i = n / 2;
    while (n%i != 0) i--;
    if (i != 1) cout << "наиб. делитель " << i << endl;
    else cout << "число простое \n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А я ведь не зря говорил о поиске наименьшего делителя... Гляньте, сколько работает [ваш код](https://ideone.com/vp0wBX) для 2142972483, и сколько - [мой](https://ideone.com/ZgWBP9). И еще - все же не стоит поощрять лень и решать такие задания за человека, которому важнее не знать, а сдать...

Comment: @Harry главное, что работает, это еще не та работа где нужна максимальная скорость

Comment: Да как сказать... Факторизация как раз задача из тех, которые могут ну очень долго выполняться. Это - никак не преждевременная оптимизация, это смена алгоритма. У вас в худшем варианте нужно перепробовать n/2-sqrt(n) вариантов, у меня - sqrt(n)/2 - можно пропускать четные. Итого разница в sqrt(n)-2 раза - даже для миллиона - в 1000 раз... Даже если вы тоже будете пропускать четные - в 500 раз. Согласитесь, разница в несколько порядков - это таки существенно :)

Comment: @Harry я понял что можно было сделать по другому, но все равно решение то рабочее(хоть можно было и лучше сделать), и почему бы галочку ему не поставить, я все таки старался

Comment: @Harry я прочитал комментарий про наименьший делитель и написал сам.

Answer (score -3):

Можно использовать следующий алгоритм (Java)

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
   if n%i==0 break;//here value i that you find
}
```

Comment: Ответ всегда будет равен самому числу n.

Comment: Вопрос к тому же про с++.

Comment: Я ответ не говорил, а подтолкнул на мысль. В алгоритме выход с цыкла на результате (см комент). А по поводу языка, виноват, не обратил внимания или тега не было

Comment: Я и говорю - результат этого кода будет само число n.